# Displaying a Chessboard in an Android App - My Runtime Error

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm having some problems understanding why my code for Android doesn't work. My objective is to make a chessboard appear on the screen.

I get this error from LogCat:

06-04 15:16:00.832: E/AndroidRuntime(885): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chess/com.example.chess.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.chess.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.chess-2.apk

I'm quite sure that MainActivity is in the build path seeing as when I look under Java Build Path my source code (Chess/src) is listed there. I'm not sure what I should try..

Please let me know if you have any ideas about what I can try to make it work, or if you need more information to try and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Try to clean your project using Eclipse.
- Try to restart eclipse
- Check your manifest file - Activity name

Comment: Also try uninstalling the apk from the phone and reinstalling.

Comment: Thank you Ishan! The problem was in the manifest file - the name of the main activity was wrong.